# Slice dataframe according to unique values into many smaller dataframes

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a large dataframe (14,000 rows). The columns include 'title', 'x' and 'y' as well as other random data.

For a particular title, I've written a code which basically performs an analysis using the x and y values for a subset of this data (but the specifics are unimportant for this).

For this title (which is something like "Part number Y1-17") there are about 80 rows.

At the moment I have only worked out how to get my code to work on 1 subset of titles (i.e. one set of rows with the same title) at a time. For this I've been making a smaller dataframe out of my big one using:

```
df = pd.read_excel(r"mydata.xlsx")
a = df.loc[df['title'].str.contains('Y1-17')]
```

But given there are about 180 of these smaller datasets I need to do this analysis on, I don't want to have to do it manually.

My question is, is there a way to make all of the smaller dataframes automatically, by slicing the data by the unique 'title' value? All the help I've found, it seems like you need to specify the 'title' to make a subset. I want to subset all of it and I don't want to have to list all the title names to do it.

I've searched quite a lot and haven't found anything, however I am a beginner so it's very possible I've missed some really basic way of doing this.

I'm not sure if its important information but the modules I'm working with pandas, and numpy

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Pandas groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html)

For example:

```
df_dict = {key: title for key, title in df.copy().groupby('title', sort=False)}
```

Which creates a dictionary of DataFrames each containing all the columns and only the rows pertaining to each unique value of title.